# Allow an NSWindow (NSPanel) to float above full screen apps

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nspanel

I'm trying to add a little window that provides "quick input" from any place in the system to the main app.

The user could hit a hotkey, the window pops up, and floats above all other windows.

For the most part, this isn't much of a problem. I can configure an NSWindow to be:

```
level = Int(CGWindowLevelKey.TornOffMenuWindowLevelKey.rawValue)
collectionBehavior = .CanJoinAllSpaces
```

I can also make it an NSPanel with `NSNonactivatingPanelMask` option set.

**The only problem is: how can I make it so that the window can pop up on the screen even if the user is on a space containing a full screen app?**

I know this is possible when the app is `LSUIElement=true` (an app without a position in the Dock), but mine isn't.

Comment: how did you know this only works when LSUIElement=true ?
Is it documented somewhere ?
I spend a day with different configurations until I reach the same conclusion, it only works with LSUIElement=true.

Is there a way of getting this same behaviour to work with LSUIElement=false ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Okay, I had the right idea, the tricky part is how all the options interact with each other. Here's what works:

- NSPanel, **not** NSWindow
- style mask: `[.borderless, .nonactivatingPanel]`

And these properties:

```
panel.level = .mainMenu
panel.collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]
```

**Swift 4.2 Code**

Create and show a panel using these settings. Then you can drag the panel onto a fullscreen app (dual monitor setup).

```
let panel2 = NSPanel(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200), styleMask: [.titled, .nonactivatingPanel], backing: .buffered, defer: true)
panel2.level = .mainMenu
panel2.collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]
panel2.orderFrontRegardless()
```

[image: Floating NSPanel above fullscreen macOS app]

Switching to borderless will prevent the user from moving your window.

```
let panel2 = NSPanel(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200), styleMask: [.borderless, .nonactivatingPanel], backing: .buffered, defer: true)
panel2.level = .mainMenu
panel2.collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]
panel2.orderFrontRegardless()
```

Comment: how to draw NSpaned on the desktop? How to display it? How to use in instead of NSWindow?

Answer (score 2):

And the Swift 4.0 translation is this..  I am still testing this, but it seems to be working.

```
self.view.window?.level = NSWindow.Level(rawValue: Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.mainMenuWindow)))
self.view.window?.collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]
```

Comment: doesn't work for me - macos 12.5.1 (21G83)

Answer (score 0):

The Swift 3.0 version of [your self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205834/allow-an-nswindow-nspanel-to-float-above-full-screen-apps#36206109) is

```
window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.mainMenuWindow))
window.collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]
```

Comment: doesn't work for me - macos 12.5.1 (21G83)